# How to reload html info to a js file?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm new with js and html.
I'm making a web page in which a part of it dynamically changes according to the option selected in a dropdown. I am using the following js script to do it.

```
function info(p){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'idProductos': p},
    url: 'conexion.php',
    success:function(data){
      if(data.status == 'ok'){
  //      datos = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#nombreSelec').text(data.result.nombre);
        $('#precioSelec').text(data.result.precio);
        $('#caracSelec').text(data.result.descripcion);
        var imagenURL = data.result.direccionImagen;
        var imagen = `
        <div class="container">
          <img id="imagenSelec" src="${imagenURL}" alt="">
          <button class="btn addToCart">Adquirir</button>
        </div>
        `
        $('#zonaImagen').html(imagen);


        }else{
            alert("User not found...");
        }
    },
    error: function(r){

    }
  });

}
```

What happens is that in another js file I need the part of html code that the first script inserts in the document. But since that part of the code is inserted after the second js reads the html, it doesn't take it into account and it doesn't appear to me.
Is there any way in which the second js reads the html document every time the option is changed?

This is the html where the above js insert the code

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="products inner" id="zonaImagen">

              </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the second js which needs to read again the html

```
const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
console.log('addToShoppingCartButtons', addToShoppingCartButtons);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code in your second JavaScript in a function:

```
function doSomething() {
    const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
    console.log('addToShoppingCartButtons', addToShoppingCartButtons);
}
```

And add a handler to be called when the deferred object is resolved that calls the function in the second script.

```
$.ajax({
    // your code
}).then(function () {
    doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the two scripts are on separate files, and are loaded at the same time, the best way i see to get this done is to trigger a custom event when the AJAX is done, then your second script can know when to run. Here is a working example:

```js
$("#zonaImagen").on("dynamic_update", function() {
  const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
  console.log('addToShoppingCartButtons', addToShoppingCartButtons);
})

$.ajax({
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    name: "paul rudd",
    movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
  },
  success: function(response) {
    var imagenURL = "imageURL";
    var imagen = `<div class="container"><img id="imagenSelec" src="${imagenURL}" alt=""><button class="btn addToCart">Adquirir</button></div>`;
    $('#zonaImagen').html(imagen);
    $("#zonaImagen").trigger("dynamic_update");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="products inner" id="zonaImagen">
    Add to cart button will go here
  </div>
</div>
```